# SQLite columns are duplicated with a number in the attribute name (Core Data)

Tags: sqlite, core-data

Inoticed that some of my attributes are duplicated in the SQLite file. For example I see two columns `ZENDDATE` and `ZENDDATE1`. The same for some other columns.
Why does it happen? How can I get rid of them (or I shouldn't)?

[image]

Comment: You could turn on core data debug logging and see if those fields are used when reading and writing to the table.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Thank you for your advice. I checked and saw that I don't fill them durig insert. But in the fetch they are presented. Maybe these are some kind of versions of attributes? I mean, if I changed some attribute once and made a new xcdatamodel it was added as a new column?

Comment: What problem(s) are you seeing that you are trying to solve here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually I figuared it out. For eg. if you have few sub-entities with the same attributes, columns will be named as ZATTR, ZATTR1, ZATTR2 and etc. 2 out of 5 my sub-entities have an `endDate` attribute.